# Stream is not ending (response is not being sent)

Tags: node.js, http, request, stream, http-post

I have this, which is so close to working:

```
app.post('/html-to-pdf', (req,res,next) => {

  log.info('got request to convert html to pdf...');

  const k = cp.spawn('pandoc', ['-f', 'html','--pdf-engine=xelatex','-t','latex']);
  req.pipe(k.stdin, {end: true}).pipe(res, {end:true});

  k.stdout.on('data', d => {
    console.log('stdout:', String(d));
  });

  res.on('data', d => {
    console.log('data:',d);
  });

});
```

I can send the route html using:

```
$ curl -d '<html>hiiii</html>' -X POST localhost:3701/html-to-pdf
```

the server will get the data, and convert it and this handler will print the right info:

```
  k.stdout.on('data', d => {
    console.log('stdout:', String(d)); // logs "hiiii"
  });
```

but the **problem** is that the response never gets sent! It just hangs forever. As you can see I used {end:true} on both pipe calls, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's because I should be doing this:

```
req.pipe(k.stdin);
k.stdout.pipe(res);
```

instead of this:

```
req.pipe(k.stdin).pipe(res);
```

I doubt the explicit {end:true} is needed in this case, but I didn't test it without.

Comment: And you don't need to pass `{end: true}`, that is the default behavior.